# Are legacy C# DataTable/SqlDataAdapters exponentially faster than SqlConnection/SqlCommand and/or LINQ to SQL DataContext.ExecuteCommand calls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, linq, import

I can't believe `DataTable/SqlDataAdapter` **massively** beat out `System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery` (tried with both Stored Procedures *and* command text) and just straight `SqlConnection/SqlCommand` `ExecuteCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery` called during looping.  I was going to finally upgrade a legacy app and thought I was being pretty clever in my new approach, but it turns out it was tortoise slow.  I went through 6 phases of code and have *rough* timings/stats, but I was just looking to see if anyone spotted something obvious knows something I don't before I dug deeper.

From my understanding of `DataTable/SqlDataAdapter` (which I haven't 'coded' for 15-20 years really), `DataTable` is maintaining a state of each row (clean, new, edited) and when you call `Update()` it sends back 'batches' of SQL commands (based on your defined Insert/Update command) to update the database appropriately.  I assume it is watching out for length of the SQL command and the number of parameters based on SQL Server limitations as well.

One thing to note, in all my implementations, the UPDATE/INSERT commands were 'identical' in terms of fields updated and WHERE clauses.  Only difference is whether they were SQL Stored Procedures or simply adhoc command text.

Let's dig in. I have an Xml document with repeating elements of xDataDef:

```
<xDataDefs>
   <xDataDef id-auth='111111111'>
      <Profile>
         <DataElements/>
      </Profile>
      <HistoryData>
         <HistoryItem hisType='Pay' hisIndex='2020'>
            <DataElements/>
         </HistoryItem>
      </HistoryData>
   </xDataDef>
</xDataDefs>
```

**File Statistics**

- `<DataElements/>` - Those are just the properties of the 'model'.  So usually 5-20 fields represented by this.
- `<xDataDef/>` - My file has 2500 xDataDef elements.
- `<HistoryItem/>` - Across all xDataDef elements, my file has 159K elements.

During processing, I loop this file with a `XmlReader` processing each xDataDef (and children) as I encounter them.

**Database Information**

Profile table - Each xDataDef element will be placed here.

- pKey - int, primary key and has a non-clustered unique
- pAuthID - holds xDataDef/@id-auth and has a non-clustered unique index.
- pProfile - holds the  xml blob.

HistoryData table - Each HistoryItem element is placed here.

- hisKey - int, primary key and has a non-clustered unique index.
- hispKey - int, foreign key to Profile has a non-clustered index.
- hisType / hisIndex - holds respective attributes.
- hisData - holds the  xml blob.
- IX_HistoryData - non-clustered unique index of hispKey/hisType/hisIndex

**Original/Baseline**

- Time: **4 minutes, 30 seconds to load entire file - 2541 Profile rows and 159K HistoryData rows**.
- Strategy: Using DataTables / SqlDataAdapters and other code that I thought was inefficient, it took 4.5 minutes to load entire file.  Explained more in Phase 6.

**Phase 1**

- Time: In 1 minute, I only imported **40 Profile rows and 2,351 HistoryData rows**.
- Strategy: Build up one query to insert or update the Profile and all associated HistoryData rows using a 'UPDATE ...IF @@ROWCOUNT == 0 THEN INSERT INTO... design.  Then execute the command for *every* profile (so about 2500 calls). The query roughly looked like this.

  DECLARE @pKey int;
  UPDATE Profile SET @pKey = pKey, pProfile = 'NewXml' WHERE pAuthID = 'AuthID'

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Profile (pProfile, pAuthID) VALUES ('NewXml', 'AuthID')
     SET @pKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  END

  UPDATE HistoryData SET hisData = 'NewXml' WHERE hispKey = @pKey AND hisType = 'Type' AND hisIndex='Index1'

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO HistoryData (hispKey, hisType, hisIndex, hisData) VALUES (@pKey, 'Type', 'Index1', 'NewXml')
  END

  UPDATE HistoryData SET hisData = 'NewXml' WHERE hispKey = @pKey AND hisType = 'Type' AND hisIndex='Index2'

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO HistoryData (hispKey, hisType, hisIndex, hisData) VALUES (@pKey, 'Type', 'Index2', 'NewXml')
  END

  [Repeating HistoryData blocks for every hisType/hisIndex row]

**Phase 2**

- Time: In 1 minute, I only imported **15 Profile rows and 941 HistoryData rows**. (also included a 55 second query to prep stuff.
- Strategy: Queried all the Profile.pKey values up front into a `Dictionary<pAuthID, pKey>` and the same thing to HistoryData.hisKey into a `Dictionary<pKey+hisType+hisIndex, hisKey>` to be able to determine whether to issue an Update or Insert statement for each Profile/HistoryItem.  While looping, I called `DataContext.ExecuteCommand/ExecuteNonQuery` on each row based on existence

**Phase 3**

- Time: In 1 minute, I only imported **17 Profile rows and 1,054 HistoryData rows**.
- Strategy: Still queried all the Profile.pKey up front, but eliminated the HistoryData.hisKey query 'up front'.  Instead called it right before processing xDataDef/HistoryData/HistoryItem rows and restricted the query to the currently processing Profile to reduce memory requirements and make the query faster.  Finally, while looping, I called `SqlCommand.ExecuteCommand/ExecuteNonQuery` on each row based on existence using the same command text as Phase 2.

**Phase 4**

- Time: In 1 minute, I only imported **16 Profile rows and 995 HistoryData rows**.
- Strategy: Still queried all the Profile.pKey up front, but **completely** eliminated the HistoryData.hisKey query.  I could do this because I was using the exact same Stored Procedures that the original `DataTable/SqlDataAdapter` used and the Stored Procedure for 'HistoryData Command' already had a UPDATE..IF NOT UPDATED...INSERT strategy in place.  During the looping, I executed SqlCommand for each Profile/HistoryItem row.  I'm surprised at how slow this was compared to original given that only difference that I think is happening is that original 'batched' statements?

**Phase 5**

- Time: In 1 minute, I only imported **291 Profile rows and 17,263 HistoryData rows**.
- Strategy: Almost back to 'original' implementation.  I filled a `DataTable` with **all** existing data from Profile table.  In my case, I already had all 2541 rows in database.  Surprised this can be efficient.  As for the HistoryData `DataTable`, it is filled with 'nothing' (the WHERE clause force no rows to be returned).

During looping, I `BeginEdit` or `NewRow` for each Profile element, set the column values and call `SqlDataAdapter.Update`.  Then, I call `NewRow` for *every* HistoryItem element for current xDataDef and set column values, finally calling `SqlDataAdapter.Update` after done.  So the number of `SqlDataAdapter.Update` calls would approximately be 2541 for Profile elements and ~(17263/2541) for HistoryItem elements.

**Phase 6**

- Time: In 1 minute, I imported **2541 Profile rows and 34,000 HistoryData Rows** (essentially back to original import time).
- Strategy: This is almost clone of original.  The results for this phase a skewed a bit because of the implementation.  It does same 'strategy' as Phase 5, with this one difference.

It processed *all* Profile rows first and only calls `SqlDataAdapter.Update` **one time** after processing all rows.  After Profile Rows, it then loops the Xml again and processes all HistoryItem elements calling `SqlDataAdapter.Update` for every 2000 rows (then clears out `DataTable.Rows` to release memory) and one more time after looping to catch any remainder rows not applied.

This scares me.  A file with only 2541 Profile elements might be ok, but we'll need to handle files as big as 60K-100K Profile Elements.  I guess I could implement a similar strategy as HistoryData rows, but there is the issue that I fill the Profile `DataTable` at the beginning with the existing population.

**Take Aways That I'll Probably Test Unless Suggested Otherwise**

1. I'm curious if I need to continue to used Stored Procedures for Phase 5-6 or if it would be 'just' as performant if I used command text instead.
2. I'm curious if I need to have an Update *and* Insert command for Profile rows, or if I could created a new Stored Procedure/command text to do the UPDATE...INSERT as needed (like the HistoryData rows).  I'm assuming I can since there are more HistoryData rows in Xml and database and it seems to perform well enough.  Then I could get rid of requirement to populate Profile `DataTable` up front.

So...are the results surprising?  I'd like to get rid of Sql* objects in the code base, but maybe that is an unwarranted desire.  I know L2S is obsolete as well, but at least it 'kind of' translates to Entity Framework if/when we move that direction.  I'd also like to not use Stored Procedures and only use command text where the code is more visible/maintainable to the developers working on it.  But if performance is the cost, then I'll forego this as well.

Is there a better way to process large Xml files and update/insert data into a SQL database?

Comment: Two thoughts here: getting the data out of the XML file should - in theory - require only a fraction of the time for inserting into the DB. Did you check this by profiling only the read times, without any DB access? And second: from your post, it is pretty unclear where your different approaches start and end a transaction / apply a commit. Maybe the `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` ends a transaction after every INSERT, but the `SqlDataAdapter` makes a commit only once? That would explain the large differences.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on this code yet to see where the hot spots are?  Despite Doc Brown's assertions, I'm not at all convinced that parsing XML files is going to be faster than looking data up in a database.  The speed at which that is accomplished is going to depend heavily on how it is done.  Hand-written parsers can be very fast.  Reflection?  Not so much.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm not using Transactions (explicitly) at all.  So if SqlDataAdapter uses them internally, I can't say.  But my SqlCommand.Execute or DataContext.ExecuteCommand aren't wrapped in any transactions by me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure where the possible notion of hand-written parsing or reflection came from, but I'm not doing either.  I'm simply using an XmlReader to loop elements, and when I encounter a 'xDataDef' element, I do var xelement = XmlReader.ReadSubTree().  Then I insert the xelement.Element( "Profile" ).ToString() and loop all the xelement.Elements( "HistoryData" ).Elements( "HistoryItem" ) and do the 'same'.  As Doc suggested, without DB access, it completes the read/processing in a second or so for everything.  So, all the pain is in DB access.

Comment: @Terry: try to use a [transaction scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707814/use-executecommand-in-linq-to-sql-with-transaction) to bundle several `ExecuteCommand` statements in one transaction. Blocks of 50 to 100 statements might be a good start. Then profile again.

Comment: Maybe, unless you have some business logic to execute before updating the database

Answer (score 1):

Excellent analysis. Writing an object graph is notoriously difficult because it can involve a lot of foreign key lookups and these are hard to implement without incurring a lot of waits. To make a dent in the performance, you need to widen your approach. Few ideas to consider:

1. Blasting all the new data into a temporary table and reconcile with the main table in a single stored procedure
2. Holding partial existing data in memory (or hashes thereof)
3. Go full blown parallel.ForEach and async. These small batches may be slow, but you can do hundreds of them concurrently

The last option is a bit hacky. Parallelizung a slow design only moves the goal posts a little bit. On the other hand, it can be a good band-aid to get relief in the short term.

Also consider the [parallel task library](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).